# What are the programming ways to solve MemoryError (raising from creating large matrices)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, out-of-memory

I got `MemoryError` from creating 4 matrices size: `(115005L, 6005L) (9738L, 6005L) (115005L, 9738L) and (115005L, 6005L)` in the same function. Now I am on `Python 2.7.13 (Anaconda 64-bit)`in Windows. Is updating python to 3.x the best way to solve the problem? Or how to solve MemoryError without modifying hardware? I have to use this PC but I have no authority to buy or add anything.

Comment: You could put more memory in your computer.

Comment: @khelwood how? like I just clear drive C or something?

Comment: @Jan just add more RAM

Answer (score 1):

You can downcast the numeric types in your data using the `.astype(t)` method to save memory to an extent. For example:

```
rr.shape
Out[69]: (15000, 35)
rr.nbytes
Out[70]: 4200000
zz = rr.astype('float16')
zz.nbytes
Out[72]: 1050000
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 is known to require more memory than Python 2.7 in many domains:

- strings are unicode so they use twice as much memory than Python 2 byte strings
- python 3 int type is equivalent of Python 2 long type so again requires more memory

Some improvement may have occur in other domains, but I would not hope that passing from Python 2 to Python 3 could solve any out of memory issue.

Increasing physical memory should be a much more reliable way.